# SwiftUI: CoreData and complex JSON

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save JSON to CoreData but the JSON is a little bit complex with many array objects. I could only save and display simple attributes like String, Int... but if I add attributes with Transformable type like [Currency], [Double], the app will crash.

Could you please show me the right way to implement this?

My Data Model

```
struct Currency: Decodable {
    let code, name, symbol: String?
}

struct Language : Decodable {
    let name : String?
}

struct WorldData: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id : Int {
        return population
    }
    var name : String?
    ...
    var latlng : [Double]?
    var currencies : [Currency]?
    var languages : [Language]
    ...
}
```

My Manual NSManagedObject subclass

```
extension CDCountry {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CDCountry> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CDCountry>(entityName: "CDCountry")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var latlng: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var currencies: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var languages: NSObject?
    ...

    public var wrapperLatlng : NSObject {
        latlng ?? ["Unknown error"] as NSObject
    }
    
    public var wrapperCurrencies : NSObject {
        currencies ?? ["Unknown error"] as NSObject
    }
...
```

and how I save loaded JSOn to CoreData

```
static func loadDataToCD(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        loadDataFromJSON { (countries) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                var tempCountries = [CDCountry]()
                for country in countries {
                    let newCountry = CDCountry(context: moc)
                    
                    ...
                    newCountry.currencies  = country.currencies as NSObject?
                    newCountry.languages = country.languages as NSObject
                    newCountry.latlng = country.latlng as NSObject?
                    newCountry.name = country.name
                    ...
                    tempCountries.append(newCountry)
                }
                do {
                    try moc.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Could not save to CD: ", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're using `Codable`, but transformable attributes require `NSCoding`. Those protocols do similar things but are not compatible. `Codable` types can't be used with transformable attributes.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to make it compatible? Thank you @Tom Harrington

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to answer your question but I can point you to some resources.

There is a good example on decoding JSON within the `Landmark.swift` file included in the  "Handing User Input" Tutorial that Apple provides for SwiftUI. That might help with the basics. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

The tutorial uses custom `Coordinates` and `Category` classes that can likely mimic the process for your `Currency` and `Language` objects. But of course that would be for a Non-Managed Object.

To do it Managed it would be best to create CoreData objects for `Currency` and `Language` and join them as a `relationship` in CoreData vs making them a `Transformable`.

Then you can follow the answer for this older question that was answered very throughly [Save complex JSON to Core Data in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555913/save-complex-json-to-core-data-in-swift)

You can also look at this question [Swift And CoreData With Custom Class As Transformable Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256336/swift-and-coredata-with-custom-class-as-transformable-object)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will try it now!